# Make two columns with adjustable heights have 100% height inside main div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have come across a problem where I have a div with two columns. I want one to be gray, the other to be white. One will have images, the other will have text. I need the height of both to be 100% and am having difficulty figuring this out. The way I have it set up now, one side "ends" and the other side continues to stretch the div.

What do I need to do to have both columns extend to the bottom of the div? the "ind-product" is the main div that contains a label, then logos (left column) and text (Right column). There will not always be equal content in both of these.

My HTML:

```
                   <div class="ind-product">
                        <div class="ind-product-label">Label Goes Here</div>
                        <div class="ind-product-logos">
                                <img src="/images/logos/1.png"  />
                                <img src="/images/logos/2.png"  />
                                <img src="/images/logos/3.png"  />
                        </div>


                                <div class="ind-product-list">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Shovels</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>

                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

                    </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.ind-product {
width:308px;
height:auto;
float:left;
background-color:#fff;
border-radius:0px;
margin:14px 20px 8px 0px;
/*border:solid #000 1px;*/
color:#202020;
}



.ind-product-label {
width:276px;
height:50px;
background-color:#ac1225;
color:#fff;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:15px;
text-align:center;
padding:20px 16px 0px 16px;
font-weight:bold;
}

.ind-product-logos {
background-color:#CBCBCB;
height:100%;
width:150px;
float:left;
}

.ind-product-list {
height:100%;
float:right;
width:158px;
}

.ind-product-list ul {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

.ind-product-list li {
padding:14px 12px 0px 12px;
list-style:none;
}
```

I want both columns inside of my div to reach 100% height. I am not understanding how this is supposed to work.

Thanks

Comment: JSfiddle.net demo please.

Answer (score 0):

width cant be given in 100% they need specefic heights in pixels or they take it from the content.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do this on your CSS

`html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}`

and also change the height in your .ind-product to a 100% so it looks like this:

```
.ind-product {
    width:308px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#fff;
    border-radius:0px;
    margin:14px 20px 8px 0px;
    /*border:solid #000 1px;*/
    color:#202020;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/E7r9y/

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to adjust the height of the smaller column when the page loads:

```
$(function() {
   var leftHeight = $('.left').css('height');
   var rightHeight = $('.right').css('height');

    // Set the height of one container to match the other.
    // You could also compare both values to find the taller
    // column first and then set the shorter one to match.
    $('.left').css('height', rightHeight);
});
```

http://goo.gl/DC02f5